# Android Problemas con la Api de Google en producción

Tags: java, android

Acabo de publicar mi aplicación en la Google Play, pero no consigo que los mapas de Google se vean correctamente. Tengo la Api en el Manifest, y mirando en casos de StackOverflow he visto soluciones pero no doy con la tecla. Si ejecuto la aplicación mediante USB con Android Studio si funciona.

Ejecuté keytool -list -v -keystore tu_keystore.keystore con sustituyendo "tu_keystore.keystore" por la jks que utilizo para firmar el bundle de la aplicacion, indico en Google Console el SHA1 que me resulta... pero nada, sigue viendose gris el mapa (solo se ve el logo de Google).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluso despues de poner la SHA1, volví a generar la Api key... Algo se me escapa seguro.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

EDITO

Acabo de ejecutarlo con el Logcat y arroja este error:

Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
2023-10-31 21:55:08.498  8335-8743  Google Maps Android API com.cruzdeguia                       E  In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
API Key: 
Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): <aqui pinta la clave sha1;com.cruzdeguia

Tengo todos los servicios Api de la biblioteca habilitados.

EDITO

Encontre en Google Play Console esta sección y he puesto los SHA1 que me salen, uno de ellos ademas coincide con el que se genera en modo debug Android Studio, el otro no coincide con el de producción que me generó al ejecutar el keytool. No se si servirá.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añado una nueva edición, siento la insistencia pero llevo dias asi y me siento bastante impotente, ya que no se que mas me queda por probar y Google no tiene mucho soporte al desarrollador. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**El problema principal es que no has registrado el SHA1 del Keystore con el cual firmas tu app para producción en Google Play, debes obtener el SHA1 de este Keystore y registrarlo**

[image: Google Play Console Jorgesys SHA1]

---

Si mencionas:

> " Si ejecuto la aplicación mediante USB con Android Studio si
> funciona."

Esto indica que la SHA1 registrada en la consola Google es la del Keystore de desarrollo, deberías tener también la SHA1 del Keystore con la cual firmas tu app a Google Play, esto en la parte "Restricciones de Android", asegura primero tener los dos SHA1 registrados.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muy importante también es verificar cual es el API Key que estás usando, debes asegurar que es la misma en la cual registraste las SHA1, ya que veo tienes una anterior, la cual tiene validez hasta el día de mañana.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Actualización:**

Comentas lo siguiente:

> La Api Key la generé cuando registré los SHA1. No se si es por ese motivo, pero la que nueva que está activa, es la que ahora mismo usa la aplicacion

Por lo tanto, **si subiste la app producción definiendo una API Key que tenía relacionado uno o varios SHA1 y volviste a regenerar la API Key, esto puede ser la causa por la cual no puedes habilitar la Google Maps API en tu app, te sugiero realices una actualización de tu aplicación con la API Key que se encuentre activa, registrando el SHA1 de tu keystore con el cual se firmó la app para Google Play**. Evita regenerar las API Key, ya que esto provocará que pierdas permisos para usar las APIs de Google.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, ahi tengo registrada la SHA1 junto con el package de mi app, solo que lo tengo tapado. Supuestamente es producción, no se como averiguarlo, el SHA1 esta generada con la keystore que utilizo para publicar la app.

Comment: Si los mapas funcionan al subir tu app desde android studio y no al subir tu app al Google Play, esto significa que ese SHA1 es del keystore de desarrollo. Los SHA1 deben ser distintos , obten el  SHA1  de esta forma : keytool -list -v -keystore tu_keystore.keystore

Comment: Justamente asi obtuve el SHA1, concretamente en el directorio del JDR de Java

Comment: @danijm21 la API Key que tienes configurada en tu app coincide con la API Key que indica en esa pantalla o esta usando la clave anterio?

Comment: Estoy usando la recien generada

Comment: he añadido la SHA1 de desarrollo y en el Logcat no da errores, muestra bien el mapa. Pero en produccón sigue sin funcionar. La Api Key la generé cuando registré los SHA1. No se si es por ese motivo, pero la que nueva que está activa, es la que ahora mismo usa la aplicacion

Comment: cuando generé la nueva api key hice una actualización con esa puesta. Lo que no recuerdo es si el sha1 de debug lo añadí a posteriori en Google Console. Volveré a generar una aplicación por si acaso.

Comment: **Los comentarios han sido [movidos al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149502/discussion-on-answer-by-jorgesys-android-problemas-con-la-api-de-google-en-produ); por favor, no continuar la discusión aquí.** Antes de publicar un comentario bajo este, por favor revisa los [propósitos de los comentarios](/help/privileges/comment). Los comentarios que no pidan clarificaciones o sugieran mejoras normalmente deben ser publicados como una [respuesta](/help/how-to-answer), en [meta], o en el [chat]. Los comentarios que continúen la discusión podrán ser eliminados.